# Expire subset of keys in multiparty encryption scheme

Tags: cryptography

Assume a multi-party encryption scheme, similar to the answer to: [Encryption with multiple different keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597188/encryption-with-multiple-different-keys).
That is. A set of keys `K` can be used to decipher a ciphertext.

Is there a way to expire:

```
K'⊆ K
```

such that that `K \ K'` can still decipher the ciphertext, but no longer `K'`?

I'm of course assuming that the cipher text has been updated as a consequence of the expiration of `K'`. I'm not really sure how to attack this, or if it's even possible?

Comment: A negative answer is also an answer... ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a problem studied by a specific branch of cryptography called *Broadcast Encryption*. In particular, it is also assumed that:

- the overhead for sending a message must be minimized
- the traffic for re-keying purposes is limited or even none
- a broadcast/multicast channel exists
- the storage each user has got is limited and sometimes cannot even be changed
- the protocol is safe even if two or more "expired" users collude together (e.g. by putting together their keys and see if together they can still access the data)
- the users have limited computational power

Several protocols exist, and each achieves a different trade-off for the conditions above. However, I am not aware of any standards around any of them.

Two very nice and seminal documents describing the problem and some solutions are:

- [Broadcast Encryption by Fiat and Naor](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~naor/PAPERS/broad_abs.html)
- [Key management for Multicast by Wallner and Harder](http://www.hjp.at/doc/rfc/rfc2627.txt)

On the internet you can find much more material, but in most cases they trace back to such two articles.

Comment: Thank you, just reading the abstracts, this seems like exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a public-key cryptosystem like PGP/GPG the answer is "no."  You'd have to somehow alter the cryptotext so that `K'` could no longer decrypt it, which means generating a new cryptotext.

Since there's no way to retract the original cryptotext, `K'` will always be able to decrypt it.

Comment: I'm assuming that the original plaintext (say 'XXX') is no longer relevant, and has been replaced by a new plaintext (say 'YYY'). It is the encrypted form of the new plaintext that can not be decrypted by K', while the keyset K \ K' can decrypt it (to produce 'YYY').