# Best practice for storing private images on a webserver

Tags: php, image, security, hash, server

For example if you had an online communitity that allowed the sending of private images between members, like a digital penpal or dating website.

What would be the best practice for securing these images on a webserver and the best practice for displaying them to the authenticated user?

Here is what I have done so far:

1. Store Images outside of public root.
2. Retrieve images via one time code instead of the actual image location.
3. Randomised hashed image names and folder names that are not easy to guess.
4. PHP script to authenticate user before displaying the image.

Outside of root seems to be one of the best ways to store the images to make then hard to access, but what about if the server itself is directly hacked into?

Is there a way to hash and salt the image files so it can only be displayed once the hash and salt matches, even if a hacker had the file? 
Would this be possible to return via PHP or SQL?
I was thinking of encoding the images to base64 and salting the base64 with a salt generated from a randomly generated password per user (Is this possible?)
Or is there a better method?

Comment: You could store them in MySQL with a binary data type, then have something like `image.php?id=123` and within this you could apply some logic like check which user is requesting the image and if they have the permissions that are required in order to access it.

Comment: Hi, I would say that databases get compromised too... so I would keep it out of the DB. As for more secure ways, I think you could use pgp keys in such a way that only the sender and the receiver can decode the file [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/597200/3727050). However, the question becomes where would you store the keys? (Note you can also protect the key with passphrase)

Comment: I was thinking maybe generated key that can only be generated if both sides of the conversation match authentication from sender and reciever, and its one time only then it changes after rendering the image.

I'm not actually building as such into a website, I am just trying to learn how others might go about this, for example even storing medical records or other highly confidential files on a webserver that can be externally viewed.

Comment: @Craig van Tonder: There are many things you can store in MySQL.  But, since it is a relational database, it is recommended that the data is relational.  Raw binary bytes of an image are not.

Comment: @urban If you're going to get hacked then you will get hacked either way and so my suggestion is not relative to network security ;)

Comment: @HoldOffHunger It's true... Maybe there are better database engines for this use case but it's still worth some thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a basic protection, the things you have described could be enough, maybe even too much in the sense that if folders are outside of www root, randomizing folder names won't add much to security but will increase complexity.

Based on a risk assessment that you should conduct for your scenario, you can choose to do more. Of course if you find that you can lower the risk of a $100 breach with the cost of $10000, you probably don't want to do that. So do the maths first. :)

I can see two major threats to your solution, one is a bug in the access control logic that allows a user to download images that he was not supposed to be able to access. The other is an attacker gaining access to your web server and downloading images (as your web server needs to have access to image files, this is not necessarily root/admin access, which increases the risk).

An idea one could think of would be to encrypt images on the server. However, with encryption, key management is usually the problem, and that is exactly the case now. There is not much point in encryption with a key that your application can access anyway, as an attacker could also access that key in case of a successful application level attack (and also in case of a server/OS level attack, because the user running your web server and/or application must have access to the key).

In theory, you could generate a public/private keypair for all of your users. When somebody uploads an image, you would generate a symmetric key for the image, encrypt the image with that key, and then encrypt the symmetric key with each intended recipient's public key and store encrypted keys (and metadata) with the image. The private keys for users should also be encrypted, preferably with a key derived from the user's password with a proper key derivation function like PBKDF2. One implication is that you can only get the user's private key when the user logs in, because you don't store his password, so that's the only time you have it. This means you would have to store your user's decrypted private key in server memory at least, where it is not really safe (and any other store is much worse). This would still provide protection against offline attackers though (somebody having access to backups for instance), and it would also limit attack scope to victim users that log on while the server is compromised (meaning after it is compromised, but before you realize this). Another drawback is the complexity of this solution - crypto is hard, it would be really easy to mess this up without experience. This would also mitigate the threat posed by an access control flaw, because unintended images could not be decrypted with the logged on user's private key.

A completely different approach would be to separate your application into several components: a logon service (similar to SSO), your web server, and a backend image service. When your user logs on to the authentication provider (AP), he would in this case receive a token with claims, signed by the AP. When talking to the web application, he would use this token for authentication. What differentiates this solution from the previous is that when a user requests images, the web application would pass his token to the image service, and the image service could on the one hand store images securely on a box not directly accessible from the internet, and on the other hand it could authorize whether for the token received it wants to return images (it could verify the token with the AP or by itself, depending on the implementation you choose). In this case, even if an attacker compromises the web application, he would still not be able to produce (sign) a valid token from the AP to get access to images on the image service, and it could potentially be much harder to compromise the image service. Of course in case of a breach on the web server, the attacker would still be able to observe any image flowing through, meaning any user that logs on while the server is compromised would still lose his images to the attacker. The added complexity of this solution is even worse than the previous one, which means it is easy to get this wrong too, and it's also costly both to develop and maintain.

Note that none of these solutions protect images from server admins, which may or may not be a requirement for your app.

I hope this answer sheds some light on the difficulties involved in making it significantly more secure than your current solution. Having said all this, implementation is key, and details (the actual code level vulnerabilities) probably matter the most.

Comment: Very interesting!

Answer (score 0):

You have these listed as some of your security protocols:

```
"1. Store Images outside of public root.

2. Retrieve images via one time code instead of the actual image location.

...

4. PHP script to authenticate user before displaying the image."
```

This should be enough, but then you mentioned...

```
"3.  Randomised hashed image names and folder names that are not easy to guess."
```

If you are actually doing the first two correctly, 1 and 2, then it's not really possible for 3 to have any effect.  If the images are outside of the webserver directory, then it doesn't matter if the folder names and image names are easy to guess.

Your code will look like (for doing 1 and 2), assuming the environment is the root directory of your webserver (i.e., example.com/index.php)...

```
$file_location = '../../images/' . $some_id_that_is_authenticated_and_cleansed_for_slashes . '.jpg';

readfile($file_location);  // grabs file and shows it to user
```

If you are doing the above, then 3 is redundant.  Hashing the names, etc., won't help if your site is hacked (the Apache security is bypassed) and it won't help if your site isn't doing the above (since users can then just directly access the URLs).  Except for that redundancy, the rest seems perfect.