# Three way encryption

Tags: encryption

I'm looking for some sort of three way encryption algorithm. So you three pairs of data (components) are encrypted, and one encrypted component can be decrypted by a key that is derived from the other two encrypted components. I thought I read about an algorithm like this in my uni years, but I can't seem to find it. I would appreciate any of the pointers I can get on this.

So to get down on what I mean, let's say I have the values A, B, C. Where encrypted versions of these are denoted as A', B', C'. In order to decrypt A' into A, a decryption key has to be derived from B' and C'. In this sense the components store the actual data intended to hide, but also store the decryption key for the other component, so the encryption can be lifted when all three components are known.

Initially I thought with the cumulative nature of the xor operation it could be accomplished with that. My idea was by creating a A' = A ^ sha1(B) ^ sha1(C), B' = B ^ sha1(A) ^ sha1(C). You could combine the keys and cancel out sha1 components. But this doesn't seem to work. So I'm looking for some algorithm that could work like what is mentioned above.

Comment: You can try to ask on https://cs.stackexchange.com or https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Related, but not the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597188/encryption-with-multiple-different-keys

Comment: @VadimKotov when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat You're right, thanks

Comment: @gnat OK, cross-posting is frowned upon, please explain to the OP what he should do given that this is not the correct site.

Comment: Consider asking in [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) and deleting this question. But you need to provide a clear description and probably an explanation on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: You state: "The decryption for A' should be based on the combination of B' and C'.", what does "based on" mean?

Comment: @zaph - well maybe 'based on' is a wrong expression. What I mean somehow B' and C' are encrypted in a way, the combination of both B' and C' can be used to decrypt A'.   While for B' this would be A' and C'.

Comment: A clearer version of this question would be on topic in crypto.

Comment: 1. Add additional information the the question, that is improve the question. 2. Encrypotion involves keys and data, there is no mention of keys. 3. It seems that you do not have a clear idea of what you want. Write a narrative of the actions.

Comment: @zaph I changed the question, hopefully structuring it better. I do have a clear idea of what I want, and I am describe it to the best of my abilities what I want the 'effect' to be, but the question to stackoverflow is 'what algorithm to use'.

Answer (score 0):

Requirement: Given three data pieces `data_A`, `data_B` and `data_C`, encrypt each in such a manor that it requires all three to create the encryption key necessary to decrypt any one.

1. Create a `master_key`, split into three components (`split_key_A`, `split_key_B` and `split_key_C`.
2. Derive an `encryption_key` from the `master_key` with PBKDF2.
3. Individually encrypt each `data_` with the `encryption_key` and prepend the encrypted data with the associated `split_key_`.
4. To decrypt, get all three encryptions, split off the `split_keys` and combine them into the `master_key`. Derive the `encryption_key` from the `master_key` with PBKDF2.
5. Decrypt any of the `data_` with the `encryption_key`.

Note: I an not a cryptographic expert, do not rely on this for production work, it may not be secure.